# mdadm puts wrong devices in array on boot Correct mdadm.conf file

Tags: linux, centos, raid, boot, mdadm

Upon boot it stuffs it up every time:

```
    [root][centos ~] cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : inactive sda[2] sdb[3]
      1953524992 blocks
unused devices: <none>
[root][centos ~] mdadm --stop /dev/md127 
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
[root][centos ~] mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 4 drives.
[root][centos ~] cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sda1[0] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      2930279424 blocks level 5, 1024k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]          
unused devices: <none>
```

You can see first it detects a BS md127, then I have to stop that one, then reassemble it, here's one weird thing, it detects two md0's but it's sucessful:

```
[root][centos ~] mdadm -Es 
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=39c28990:e753d835:8b94c90b:72da1a08
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=88edc937:2ecbc9bb:8b94c90b:72da1a08
```

my mdadm.conf

```
[root][centos ~] cat /etc/mdadm.conf
DEVICE partitions 
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=88edc937:2ecbc9bb:8b94c90b:72da1a08
MAILADDR root 
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes
HOMEHOST <system>
```

But the weirdest thing, in dmesg, I think the problem lies here:

```
md: kicking non-fresh sdc from array!
md: unbind<sdc>
md: export_rdev(sdc)
md: kicking non-fresh sdd from array!
md: unbind<sdd>
md: export_rdev(sdd)
async_tx: api initialized (async)
xor: automatically using best checksumming function: generic_sse
   generic_sse:  6532.000 MB/sec
xor: using function: generic_sse (6532.000 MB/sec)
raid6: int64x1   1664 MB/s
raid6: int64x2   2148 MB/s
raid6: int64x4   1453 MB/s
raid6: int64x8   1457 MB/s
raid6: sse2x1    2417 MB/s
raid6: sse2x2    3222 MB/s
raid6: sse2x4    3429 MB/s
raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (3429 MB/s)
md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
raid5: device sda operational as raid disk 2
raid5: device sdb operational as raid disk 3
raid5: allocated 4282kB for md127
2: w=1 pa=0 pr=4 m=1 a=2 r=4 op1=0 op2=0
3: w=2 pa=0 pr=4 m=1 a=2 r=4 op1=0 op2=0
raid5: not enough operational devices for md127 (2/4 failed)
RAID5 conf printout:
 --- rd:4 wd:2
 disk 2, o:1, dev:sda
 disk 3, o:1, dev:sdb
raid5: failed to run raid set md127
md: pers->run() failed ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it, it was a problem with my mdadm.conf file not being specific enough and possibly confusing for the OS.

So I read this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html

And I found that if I use this

```
DEVICE partitions
```

Then:

> This  will  cause mdadm to read /proc/partitions and include all devices and partitions found therein

So I've changed it to

`DEVICE /dev/sd[abcd]1`

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to rebuild your `initrd` so that it has the correct `mdadm.conf` file in it because the boot process has to use that version until it can get the root filesystem mounted.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
mkinitrd /boot/initrd-<kernel-version>.img <kernel-version>
```

I'm assuming here that the CentOS version you're using is still using `mkinitrd` - if it has switched to `dracut` then you will want:

```
dracut /boot/initramfs-<kernel-version>.img <kernel-version>
```

In either case you will need to rename the old file first before you can build the new one.

Comment: The root file system is getting mounted no problems so I don't know if this step is necessary. The raid is on a different mount just for storage.

Answer (score 1):

mdadm should be able to asseble a md device. It seems as it is seeing some wrong drives:

md127 : inactive sda[2] sdb[3]

That looks like it's taking the whole sda and sdb disks for the raid array, and not the partitions sda1 sdb1 sdc1 sdd1.

What does blkid show?
what does mdadm -E /dev/sda or mdadm -E /dev/sdb show?

Maybe there is something strange going on with the superblocks.

As TomH said you should also try to rebuild initrd.

Comment: Ok blkid is here along with mdadm -E http://pastebin.com/gUM3S5dm I think I can see that md0 now has a completely different UUID in that output so I'll try that

Comment: The two UIDs should be the same, so try fixing that and see if it helps. But I don't know an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu I solved this problem with this:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```